# How to use a jwt from a different issuer?

Tags: python, flask, jwt, thingsboard, flask-jwt-extended

I am building an flask API that will manipulate data to be used in thingsboard.

Long story short, client logs in via thingsboard, get a jwt from that.

But the API rejects the jwt saying that signature verification failed.

Same secret key is being used on both sides.

Both thingsboard is on a remote server, API is currently local during development.

New to jwt manipulation, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `JWT_AUTH_USERNAME_KEY` fit with the username that the library uses to get the user.
For example, when you get a Thingsboard JWT the username is in the `sub` key, and many libraries use `username` by default.

Maybe this piece of code can help you ([implementation with JWT Rest Framework](http://jpadilla.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/):

```py
class CustomAuth(JSONWebTokenAuthentication):

    def authenticate_credentials(self, payload):
        """
        Returns an active user that matches the payload's user id and email.
        """
        User = get_user_model()

        # Thingsboard payload
        if payload.get('sub') is not None:
            username = payload.get('sub')
        else:
        # Our payload
            username = payload.get('username')
        if not username:
            msg = _('Invalid payload.')
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(msg)

        try:
            user = User.objects.get_by_natural_key(username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            msg = _('Invalid signature.')
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(msg)

        if not user.is_active:
            msg = _('User account is disabled.')
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(msg)

        return user
```

Answer (score 0):

Version 3.21.0 of flask-jwt-extended adds a `JWT_DECODE_ISSUER` option which should solve this for you: https://github.com/vimalloc/flask-jwt-extended/releases/tag/3.21.0